# Angular 5 routing for child module is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

I am developing a Web application using Angular 5. I am new to Angular with Typescript. Now I am configuring the route for my application modules. But it is not working and throwing an error.

This is my `index.html` file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Web</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>
</html>
```

I created an `app-routing.module.ts` file under the app folder.

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


    const routes: Routes = [ 
        { path: '', loadChildren: './web/web.module#WebModule' },
    ];

    @NgModule({
        imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
        exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule {}


Import that routing class in the app.module.ts file

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Route } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then created another module, `web/web.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { WebRoutingModule  } from './web-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    WebRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [HomeComponent]
})
export class WebModule { }
```

This is my `web-routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class WebRoutingModule { }
```

As you can see I am rendering `HomeComponent`. I created home component user `web/home/` folder.

According to my code, if I access my website just like this, `localhost:4200`, it should render the home component HTML in the router-out in the `index.html` file. Now it is not rendering the home component HTML. It is rendering the index.html but without home, component replaced in the router-outlet. So, what is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>` has to be in the markup of `app-home` not in the index.html file for it to work

I have just set up routing in one of my projects.

My `app.component.ts` looks like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
}
```

My `app.component.html` looks like this

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My `app-routing.module.ts` look like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// Layouts
import { MasterComponent } from './components/layouts/master/master.component';
// Main Pages
import { HomeComponent } from './components/pages/home/home.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './components/pages/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MasterComponent, children: [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  ] },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Also my index.html file looks like this

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Office</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your welcomes, I've set up Routes within angular on loads of different projects now. Glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

Try providing your web.module in app.module's  imports array